# marca de agua con java

Tags: java

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        /
        JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser(ruta_archivo);
        FileNameExtensionFilter fi = new FileNameExtensionFilter("pdf", "pdf");

        j.setFileFilter(fi);
        int se = j.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (se == 0) {
            ruta_archivo = j.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            //----------------
            //Usamos el metodo abrir pdf para mostrarlo
            abrir_pdf(ruta_archivo);



        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No selecciono");
        }
    }
```

Buenas tardes trato de hacer una aplicacion con interfaz grafica en java puse un boton para abrir un pdf pero ya no se como hacer una clase desde btnbutton para poner una marca de agua a puros archivos pdf me podrian ayudar gracias 
solo llevo eso de codigo